# Fundamentally, can the "this" keyword be the same in C# vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, strong-typing

I am getting into a fundamental argument about strongly typed, and statically typed languages. The other debater is a pure javascript enthusiast. While I enjoy working with both c# and javascript. The conversation arose over the discussion about TypeScript and how it's better than pure js because it is strongly typed. (subjective already). So I provided him with an argument that TypeScript already fails at what it is attempting to do with the following example.

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

var greeter = new Greeter("world");
var greetWorld = greeter.greet;
alert(greetWorld()); //undefined, unexpected for strongly typed languages
```

I have already said this is expected in JS. In fact, I love this. This is why it being a dynamically typed language is so powerful. But, the 'this' keyword is nothing more than a property in JS and why TypeScript is just an additional layer adding to confusion and making it no better.

"When a function is created, a keyword called this is created (behind the scenes), which links to the object in which the function operates."(JS).

Well this is truly just a property of the function/object then. The definition of strongly typed: " each type of data (such as integer, character, hexadecimal, packed decimal, and so forth) is predefined as part of the programming language and all constants or variables defined for a given program must be described with one of the data types." So the data-type function/object are separate, keyword "ONE" of the data types.

I just can't seem to drive the argument home. In fact, I might even be wrong. To me though, the problem above is a runtime type error, that their is no `greeting` even though it should be expected if the 'this' keyword were truly bound in the programming language.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know if you're missing anything, but I fear I'm missing your point. What's the question? One thing I can tell you, though: If somebody persistently can't grasp what you're telling him, at least one of you is either retarded or unwilling to listen. And that means it's time to cut your losses, shake hands, and go do some homework to make sure you're not the retarded one.

Comment: I think it's unfair to say that just because TypeScript can't replicate every behavior of a strongly-typed language, it is "no better" than JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, the keyword `this` refers to the current ***calling context***, as opposed to the ***current instance*** in C#.

In the following lines:

```
var greetWorld = greeter.greet;
greetWorld(); //returns "Hello, " + Window.greeting
```

You are calling `greetWorld()` using `Window` context, so `this` will refer to the `Windows` object.

If you want to simulate the C# behaviour you'd have to *bind* your greeter's object context to the function:

```
var greetWorld = greeter.greet.bind(greeter);
greetWorld(); //returns "Hello, " + greeter.greeting
```

Alternatively:

```
var greetWorld = greeter.greet;
greetWorld.bind(greeter)();
```

Comment: The point is. Great. You can use .bind. Great it's undefined if not. But that makes it not strongly typed. There is unexpected behavior, that resulted in a runtime TYPE error. Am I taking crazy pills? I understand how this works.

Comment: @ChrisClark It is not unexpected. That's how the language works. You may get a runtime error, depending if `greeting` property is present on the current context or not. If you were to have `Window.greeting = "Matt"`, then your example would alert `Hello, Matt`

Comment: That's literally the definition of a type error. You are getting downvoted because you are just trying to explain how 'this' works in JS. Not addressing the connection. Between statically types/strongly typed etc.

Comment: @ChrisClark But *it's not unexpected*.

Comment: @ChrisClark so you're downvoting him because he didn't add a sentence saying "Yes, even with TypeScript, JavaScript is not the same as C# when it comes to strong typing"?

Comment: @dman2306 The title is, 'Fundamentally, can the “this” keyword be the same in C# vs Javascript?' Not teach Chris how "this" works in javascript, and when he says that's not strongly typed, be baffled.

Comment: @ChrisClark I'm telling you ***no***. Fundamentally, the `this` in JavaScript is completely different than the `this` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

In C# the this keyword is available inside any class method and refers to the current object used to invoke the method. When I first started writing JavaScript I assumed that it would be the same, but soon found out that I was wrong. this in JavaScript has a different behaviour.

Check out this [Link](https://coding.abel.nu/2013/02/this-in-javascript-vs-c/)

Answer (score 1):

In JS all Objects are reference types and Functions are Objects. Which means when you assign an object's method (a function definition) in another object the originally defined method gets invoked (it does not get cloned into the new object). That also means, we need to differentiate the `this` that resides in the method according to whoever invokes it.

```
var o = { name: "A"
        , sing: function(){console.log(this.name)}
        },
    p = { name: "B"
        , sing: o.sing  // we refer to o.sing and the this in o.sing should now become p
        },
    q = { name: "C"};   // does not even have a sing method

o.sing();               // <- A
p.sing();               // <- B
o.sing.call(q);         // <- C -- the call function shifts the context of o.sing to q
```

So the `this` in `o.call` floats to the object from where it's called from.